# Pasting from Windows host to Ubuntu 18.04 LTS Guest

Tags: 18.04, virtualbox

So I tried a few things so the iso tools

```
Guest additions image

sudo apt-get install virtualbox-guest-dkms
```

However non of these seem to work, I tried a few solutions. I need to copy a vpn certificate and I really can't type it by hand.

Comment: Did you set the clipboard function to Bidirectional? https://www.liberiangeek.net/2013/09/copy-paste-virtualbox-host-guest-machines/

Comment: `Yes, however for now I fixed my issue with a viso but since this is a test setup I would love to have it workin instead of making lose textfiles I would have to output to what I need. The way I do it now if the extension is avaible and workin on Windows 10 I do that.  

Otherwise my work arround is a textfile 

    cat file.txt > neededthing.sh